# How can I repair deep flaking on a 1930s wall?

Tags: walls, bedroom

the walls of my room are bumpy and have some tears in the outer layer.

Is this drywall or could it be plaster and lath? And if drywall, do I have to change the whole walls or just the bumpy batches?

The house is old, I think was built in 30s. I wonder if anyone can tell me if this is a drywall or plaster? If drywall, do I have to change the whole walls or just the bumpy patches? I'm tempted to repair it myself but need some guidance.

[image: pic of failed finish]

Comment: Agreed, that looks bumpy to me... is there a question here?

Comment: If it is too much, remove drywall and install new drywall.  It is actually a DIY job.

Comment: If a small section can be patched, but once it goes pass about 1/3 or half might be better to re do the whole wall.  Will be almost as fast.

Comment: Note that from the bottom corner, it appears that there's a crack that continues along the wall. You'll want to remove all the cracked plaster as well, as it's likely to fail in the near future. Easier to fix it all now then to have to do another fix in a few months or a year.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like either many coats of paint or a skimcoat of some sort. In either case it didn't bond well, and the fix is the same since it's mostly a surface issue. A 1930s home almost certainly has plaster, but lath type varies by region. Hopefully you don't need to get into that.

1. Using a putty knife or other scraping tool, remove all loose material. It may help to cut football shaped areas out with a knife, leaving secure edges.
2. Skim the deeper repairs with a high quality material such as setting-type* joint compound. I like Easy Sand 90, for example. Use cool water and mix small batches. It is more difficult to sand than modern joint compound, so keep your repairs flat and thin. You can easily add more in subsequent layers.
3. Prime the wall with a quality product which claims to bond well to enamel and semi-gloss paints.
4. Optionally skim the entire wall with a topping compound for a very flat finish.
5. Optionally texture the wall.
6. If you've skimmed or textured, prime *again*.
7. Apply your topcoat.

Drywall work and painting are well covered in other posts here and online. If you're new to either, I suggest some study of technique before beginning. Good luck.

---

* Setting type compounds bond better, are tougher, and don't shrink nearly as much as premixed compounds. They also tolerate occasional moisture much better. I use them for more difficult repairs of either drywall or plaster. Follow package instructions carefully, and don't use warm water. You'll be stunned by how quickly the stuff sets up due to heat, ruining your batch (and possibly your bucket).

Comment: My house was made in the early 1930s, and it used drywall. I think that stuff was more common in the early 20th century than you think.

Comment: By drywall do you mean paper-gypsum-paper only? Gypsum lath behind plaster was common into the 50s, but I've never seen true drywall in the house that old.

Comment: No, I mean drywall. Gypsum sandwiched between paper, in 4x8 sheets. I got a pretty good look at it when I was ripping out the bathroom walls. I even saw a sticker on the back saying when it was made, so I knew it was original. I was surprised too.

Comment: Step #4: a very flat finish takes a lot of skill and is one of the main reasons (IMHO) that most walls have a textured finish. The fact that this wall isn't super flat and has bumps and runs is an indicator of that. Something for the OP to consider before attempting to do the whole wall. Getting a super flat finish for just the patched area would be much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the photo, I can't say whether it's drywall or plaster & lath. The only reliable way to tell is by cutting the wall open, or finding some place where there's already a hole in the wall. It's kind of a moot point, though: if you're replacing the whole thing with new drywall, then it doesn't matter, the procedure is the same in both cases. If you're only fixing a few small holes, then the procedure is also the same.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like wall paper was put on to smooth or give a pattern. It and has been painted several times. The painted paper is now separating from the plaster. I would glue the remaining paper to the plaster then fill the low area with caulk or plaster. It was standard in the 60's in older apartments (Chicago) to have layers of wallpaper and multiple paint layers. Wall paper can be removed with a steamer and lots of hand labor.

Comment: The question starts by saying "the _walls_" (emphasis added), so it's probably not the ceiling. ;)